# Comando git stash sumiu com arquivos

Tags: git

Estava trabalhando em uma atualização importante no sistema da empresa e precisei resolver outro problema, então acabai colocando as alterações que fiz em *stash* para mudar de *branch* e baixar o *master* mais atualizado para resolver esse outro problema.

Para minha tristeza quando rodei o *stash*, ele não adicionou algumas atualizações que estavam na minha pasta `vendor`. Na verdade ele criou a pasta em branco, mas não existe arquivos.

Alguém sabe se tem como recuperar meus arquivos?

> Obs.: Não havia dado nenhum *commit* para essa atualizações que fiz.

Comment: Infelizmente não amigo, talvez o histórico da sua IDE possa ter alguma coisa.

Comment: Acho que vou desistir mesmo. Pesquisei e não encontrei solução. O que me intriga é que o git sumiu com arquivos importantes e não sei qual foi a causa.

Comment: Você já uso *git reflog* para tentar entender o que aconteceu?

Comment: @LucasRivoiro voce pode ter feito pull ou reset sem ter commitado os arquivos, é comum esse tipo de confusão =/

Comment: @egomesbrandao Eu usei o reflog mas não encontrei nada lá. porém entendi o meu erro. Vou colocar como resposta. Abraços!

Comment: @FelipePaetzold Pior que não foi esse o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

venho colocar um ponto final pois não houve formas de recuperar os arquivos. Porém eu entendi o problema e vou explicar para que ninguém cometa o mesmo erro que eu.

Como eu disse, estava editando uma pasta que estava em *vendor* e essa pasta foi baixada utilizando o *composer* de um repositório *Git*. Eu precisei edita-la mas ela tinha uma outra pasta *.git* que acabou conflitando e não deixando o meu *git* enxergar as alterações que realizei na classe. Então eu refiz algumas alterações e deletei a pasta *.git* e ai eu pude realizar o *stash* ou até dar *commit* ser perder minhas atualizações.

Comment: Nunca é demais lembrar que a pasta `vendor` é justamente pra arquivos de terceiros, por isso normalmente é ignorada no GIT (pra não versionar duas vezes o mesmo código). Se você precisa alterar alguma coisa ali é melhor fazer um `fork` do repositório do projeto e alterar no `composer.json` pra ele usar a sua cópia. Assim você fica com o controle - mas tb fica responsável pela atualização. Deletar a pasta `.git` só vai fazer com que você não receba atualizações do desenvolvedor original, o que pode tornar seu código inseguro no futuro.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica amigo! Sou novo no uso do git e ainda não manjo muito de composer. Vou dar uma estudada no que vc falou. Abraços!